# MS SQL - how to join to a table using an XML node (XML contained in a field)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have some SQL code that returns a set of records, including a cross apply that breaks out XML from a joined table and queries the XML.  This works well, however I need to see records from the base table, even if there is no match in the XML.

For example, the following code works, but will only show records if there is a match in the XML for the WHERE clause below (Eye Exam, HgA1c and the PCDate > 3/1/2014).

What I need is to show my Encounter_ExamDetails/EcounterInfoView data, even if there is no XML match.   Usually when these are just tables, I use a join (like the left joins below):

```
 select 
  EncounterInfoView.AppointmentDate,
  pref2.value('(PCare/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as PCARE,
  TRY_PARSE(pref2.value('(PCDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS date) as PCDate,
  pref2.value('(PCareComm/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as PCareComm

from
  Encounter_ExamDetails 
  left join dbo.Encounter_PhysicalExam on dbo.Encounter_PhysicalExam.FormID = dbo.Encounter_ExamDetails.FormID
  left join EncounterInfoView on EncounterInfoView.EncounterID = dbo.Encounter_PhysicalExam.EncounterID
  left join [dbo].[Encounter_History] on   [dbo].[Encounter_History].EncounterID = dbo.Encounter_PhysicalExam.EncounterID

CROSS APPLY
    HIST_PCARE.nodes('/PCareH/PCareList/PCareItem') AS PCARE(pref2)

WHERE
  (EncounterInfoView.AppointmentDate BETWEEN ('2014-03-01') and ('2014-04-01'))
    and
        (
            (pref2.value('(PCare/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') = 'Eye Exam'
            or  pref2.value('(PCare/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') = 'HgA1c'
            or pref2.value('(PCare/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') IS NULL)
            and TRY_PARSE(pref2.value('(PCDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS date) >= '2014-03-01' 
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use an outer apply instead of cross apply.

This should do the trick:

```
 select 
  EncounterInfoView.AppointmentDate,
  pref2.value('(PCare/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as PCARE,
  TRY_PARSE(pref2.value('(PCDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS date) as PCDate,
  pref2.value('(PCareComm/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as PCareComm

from
  Encounter_ExamDetails 
  left join dbo.Encounter_PhysicalExam on dbo.Encounter_PhysicalExam.FormID = dbo.Encounter_ExamDetails.FormID
  left join EncounterInfoView on EncounterInfoView.EncounterID = dbo.Encounter_PhysicalExam.EncounterID
  left join [dbo].[Encounter_History] on   [dbo].[Encounter_History].EncounterID = dbo.Encounter_PhysicalExam.EncounterID

OUTER APPLY
    HIST_PCARE.nodes('/PCareH/PCareList/PCareItem') AS PCARE(pref2)

WHERE
  (EncounterInfoView.AppointmentDate BETWEEN ('2014-03-01') and ('2014-04-01'))
    and
       (
            (pref2.value('(PCare/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') = 'Eye Exam'
            or  pref2.value('(PCare/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') = 'HgA1c'
            or pref2.value('(PCare/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') IS NULL)
            and (TRY_PARSE(pref2.value('(PCDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS date) >= '2014-03-01'
            or TRY_PARSE(pref2.value('(PCDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS date) is null)
        )
```

Comment: it looks like that helps, as I am now getting the NULL value records.   however, it is still eliminating records when I have the try_parse date > 3/1.   I believe it's because this is in the where clause, so it's reducing the selection.   It's like I need a way to 'outer apply' with a where clause only on that outer apply, not on the whole selection.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I believe you should get some results now.  The TRY_PARSE was probably returning null, which was causing the results to be excluded.  Give this a try and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That adds some records, but just a few.   I think the problem is, the is null will find the existence of a record, but with a value of null.   What I actually need it to do, is return the records from the base table (Encounter_ExamDetails) even if there are NO records in the pref2 XML (PCare/PCDate).

Comment: I ended up using temporary tables, pulling the xml in and then I just select the records from the base table and join to temp.